# Bayesian estimation for Pearson r correlation in R

Tags: r, bayesian, correlation

I'm trying to do Bayesian estimation for Pearson $r$ correlation using [Fisher's r to z transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation). But I'm wondering if I have defined the `likelihood` accurately in my work below (`R` code)?

(***Note:*** The posterior will be `function(x) prior(x)*likelihood(x)` based on Bayes' theorem.)

```
    m <-  0  # prior mean
    s <- .1  # prior sd
prior <- function(x) dnorm(atanh(x), m, s) * 1/(1-x^2) # `x` denotes `Pearson r`

 n <-  30           # Sample size (i.e., # of pair of datapoints)
SE <- 1/sqrt(n - 3) # Standard Error
 r <- .5            # Observed Correlation

likelihood <- function(x) dnorm(atanh(r), atanh(x), SE)
```

Comment: I am curious, why would you want to do Bayesian estimation of the Pearson $r$ correlation? I would love to learn more. Care to provide a link where this is useful?

Comment: If I were doing this, I would do normal Bayesian regression and then transform the distribution of the regression coefficient since $\rho = \hat{\beta} SD(y)/SD(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bayesian model of correlation with bivariate normal data using the Fisher transformation**

There are a few issues here.  Firstly, you need to distinguish between the true correlation $\rho$ in the bivariate normal distribution (which is an unknown parameter) and the Pearson correlation $r$ (which is an observed statistic).  Since the latter is a function of the observed data, there is no "estimation" process applicable to it - once observation occurs, it is known with certainty.  This is evident in your coding, since you have defined `r <- 0.5` as an observed value, but then purport to be trying to make an "estimate" of this quantity.

Presumably, what you really mean to do is to use the observed Pearson correlation $r$, together with its approximate distribution based on Fisher's transformation, to estimate the underlying correlation parameter $\rho$.  That would require you to set a prior distribution for $\rho$ and then apply the likelihood that emerges from the approximate distribution of the transformed Pearson correlation.

---

**Simple Bayesian model:** To facilitate the analysis, define the quantities:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
z &\equiv \text{arctanh}(r), \\[6 pt]
z_\rho &\equiv \text{arctanh}(\rho).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

We use a normal prior for $z_\rho$ with mean $\mu$ and precision $\lambda > 0$.  Using the approximate distribution of $z$ and treating $n>3$ as a fixed value gives us the Bayesian model:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p(z_\rho) &\propto \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda}{2} (z_\rho - \mu)^2 \right), \\[8 pt]
p(z | z_\rho) &\propto \exp \left( - \frac{n-3}{2} (z - z_\rho)^2  \right).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

By [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) we obtain the resulting posterior:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p(z_\rho | z) 
 &\propto \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda}{2} (z_\rho - \mu)^2 - \frac{n-3}{2} (z - z_\rho)^2 \right) \\[8 pt]
&\propto \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda}{2} z_\rho^2 + \lambda \mu z_\rho - \frac{n-3}{2} z_\rho^2 + (n-3) z z_\rho \right) \\[8 pt]
&= \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda + n-3}{2} z_\rho^2 + (\lambda \mu + (n-3) z) z_\rho \right) \\[8 pt]
&\propto \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda + n-3}{2} \left( z_\rho - \frac{\lambda \mu + (n-3) z}{\lambda + n-3} \right)^2 \right) \\[8 pt]
&\propto \text{N} \left( z_\rho \Bigg| \mu_{\text{post}} = \frac{\lambda \mu + (n-3) z}{\lambda + n-3}, \lambda_{\text{post}} = \lambda + n-3 \right) \\[8 pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The posterior distribution is normal, with updated mean and precision parameters.  The resulting posterior for the untransformed correlation parameter $\rho$ can be obtained from the posterior for $z_\rho$.  The density can be obtained analytically as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p(\rho | r) &= \frac{1}{1-\rho^2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\lambda + n-3}{2 \pi}} \cdot \\[8 pt]
&\text{ } \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda + n-3}{2} \left( \text{arctanh} (\rho) - \frac{\lambda \mu + (n-3)}{\lambda + n-3} \cdot \text{arctanh}(r) \right)^2 \right).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

---

**Special case - diffuse prior:** In the special case where $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ we approach a highly diffuse improper prior but we obtain a proper posterior with posterior mean $\mu_{\text{post}} \rightarrow z$ and posterior precision $\lambda_{\text{post}} \rightarrow n-3$.  In this case we have:

$$p(\rho | r) = \frac{1}{1-\rho^2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n-3}{2 \pi}} \cdot
\exp \left( - \frac{n-3}{2} \left( \text{arctanh} (\rho) -  \text{arctanh}(r) \right)^2 \right).$$

---

**Coding this model:** It is simple to simulate from the posterior distribution by generating values of $z_\rho$ and transforming these to values of $\rho$.  Posterior simulation can be done with the following code:

```
#Set your prior parameters
mu     <- 0;
lambda <- 0;

#Enter the observed statistics
n      <- 30;
r      <- 0.5;

#Simulate k correlation values from the posterior
lambda_post <- (lambda + (n - 3));
mu_post     <- (lambda*mu + (n - 3)*atanh(r))/lambda_post;
SIM         <- rnorm(k, mean = mu_post, sd = sqrt(1/lambda_post));
SIM_POST    <- tanh(SIM);

#The vector SIM_POST contains k values from the posterior for the correlation parameter
```

You can easily simulate any number of values from the posterior distribution or plot this distribution analytically.  This should give you everything you need in this kind of problem.

Comment: Ben, thank you so much! I guess there is a problem in your `R` code for the line `SIM`? I guess `var` must be changed to `sd` and then `1/lambda_post` could become `sqrt(1/lambda_post)`? Could you please confirm this?    **ALSO**, can we use any other prior than normal?     Thank you so very much.

Comment: The precision $\lambda$ is the inverse of the variance, so the prior standard deviation for $z_\rho$ is $\mathbb{S}(z_{\rho}) = 1/ \sqrt{\lambda}$.  If you want the corresponding prior standard deviation for $\rho$, that would require a bit of work to get the standard deviation of the distribution of the transformed normal variable.

Comment: Also, I have edited the R code so fix he previous error.

Comment: I've assigned ```lambda <- 0``` in the above code, so that would be the diffuse improper prior.  Any non-negative value can be used by changing the relevant line of code.  The rest of the code should work fine for any non-negative value of ```lambda``` and any value of ```mu```.

Comment: Thank you Ben, it looks like the exact analytic posterior is also possible [**THIS WAY**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.01188.pdf)? But is this doable in R? And some `R` code to obtain the exact posterior is available [**HERE (line 730 onwards)**](https://github.com/jasp-stats/jasp-desktop/blob/development/JASP-Engine/JASP/R/correlationbayesian.R#L730), but my skills are not so developed to adapt the code. If you get a chance to provide this, I'm sure, it will be highly appreciated by the community.

Comment: If by "informative" you mean that you want something that represents a prior belief that favours a particular range of values, I would suggest that this can be accomplished within the above framework by setting $\mu$ to you prior mean and setting $\lambda$ (the prior precision) as a reasonably high value.  Since the prior precision parameter is a measure of prior "pseudo data-points", that will lead to a strong "informative" prior.

Comment: So long as you remember to define ```prior.mu``` and ```prior.lambda``` that works fine.

Comment: Try ```prior.lambda <- 4``` if you want a nice hump-shaped curve.

Comment: Answered above (second comment on this thread).

Comment: Dear Ben, just in case [**This Bayesian Question**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331607/is-multilevel-regression-appropriate-for-a-simple-pre-post-control-design) might fall within your expertise?